# How do i dynamically display my json decoded data into a ul

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

i am sorry if this question has been asked before I couldn't seem to find something to answer this.

Below is my Json decoded array:

```
cart_id:1
cart_items:
  1:
    cost:4
    name:"Titleist Pro V1"
    quantity:4
  2:
    cost:1
    name:"Titleist Pro V1x"
    quantity:1
```

How can i dynamically display this into html using JQuery or javascript? I have figured out to be able to display a single variable by using this:

```
$result['cart_items']['1']['name'];
```

This will give me "Titleist Pro V1" in return. 
I am struggling with a lot of errors from all sides and felt the code itself would be too messy to paste here. It would be amazing if somebody could please just show me how i can dynamically create this data into an ul using the next pasted format with a loop or something.

```
<ul>
  <li> $name x $quantity <br> cost: $cost</li>
  <li> $name x $quantity <br> cost: $cost</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: I meant to show the top list bit as pure html but stackoverflow is converting it too an actual list, i hope its still understandable.

> NOTE: My data is brought in from a database through laravel/php. i
>   receive an json encoded file that i then proceed to decode with:

```
$result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
```

I need to be able to take any amount of results and display a list of items and their costs. Sorry if this is a lot of trouble, I'm struggeling with Laravel at the moment and things feel very overwelming.

Thank you for all your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your JSON to be in the below format

```
$result = {
  "cart_id" : 1,
  "cart_items": {
      "1": {
        cost:4,
        name:"Titleist Pro V1",
        quantity:4
      },
      "2": {
        cost:1,
        name:"Titleist Pro V1x",
        quantity:1
      }
  }
};
```

You could use jQuery [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method to loop through the object to generate an `<ul>` using the code below

```
var b = "<ul>";

$.each($result['cart_items'], function(property, value) {
  b += "<li>" + value['cost'] * value['quantity'] + "<br/>" + "cost " + value['cost'] + "</li>";
});

b += "</ul>";

$(".container").html(b);
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdLEBb